# Optimization of multivariable function with more than one root.

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

I have been trying to solve this problem:  Find the pair  $(x,y)$ ,where
$ x \in \left[0, \sqrt2\right]$ and $y \in [0,1]$ , such that the following expression has the lowest possible positive value: 
$$
z = x + \sqrt{\frac{13}{9} -2y +y^2}
      + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} - 2\sqrt{x^2 -y^2} +x^2 -y^2}
$$

I am only talking about the real positive square roots in this post. 
The brackets are parentheses.

I have been trying to sove this problem by differentiation, by setting $z=z(x)$ and assuming y is a constant,  (or)  $z=z(y)$ and assuming x is a constant. However, I havent been able to find an expression $z'(x)$ or $z'(y)$   such that i can actually solve the equation   $z'(x)=0$ or $z'(y)=0$ .   I don't really have any experience in multi-variable calculus, so i really hope somebody can help me :P

And I don't want any approximate solution, if possible.

And, It may be that the solution is $y=1/12$ and $x=\sqrt{193} / 84$ , but I can't find a way to prove it algebraically...

Robin

Comment: Are you familiar with the first and second derivative tests? They can be generalized to multiple variables via the *total derivative*.

Comment: As for formatting: use dollar signs to delimit formulas (and TeX code within), though most of what you have is equivalent to the TeX code already).

Comment: The solution is not $y=1/12$ and $x=193^{1/2}/84$ because at that point the partial derivative of the objective function with respect to $y$ is nonzero (we require both partial derivatives to be zero at an interior minimizer).

Comment: Hey, im not familiar with the derivative tests Yet. The reason I added y=(1/12) and x=193^0.5 /84 is because they where apparently the solution to this problem practically formulated (But unfortunately I cannot find the problem itself in any of my books.....)  However, the way they solved the problem in the book was by logic, BUT I wanted to see how one would solve it algebraically.